# How to use TeamCity to emulate VisualStudio Publish Web feature

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity

Visual Studio (VS) offers a 'Publish Web' feature, from which you select a profile & it generates the build artfects - this works as expected, my Web.config is transformed from the profile (say web.Test.config).

If I build via teamcity using /p:Configuration="Test" , the build is good, but I dont see any transformation - Is my expectation Ok. I do have octoPack run set.

I do have other VS projects, were I use team city to build nuget packages, that are then deployed to various enviroment via Octopus. Where Octopus does the transformations. I think I'm confusing my expectation of teamcity i.e. its not an emulation of VS's Publish-Web. And I must use both steps teamcity + octopus to buid an output deliverable even if i dont use octopus to deploy to the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work, you must have your configuration in Publish Configuration File *.pubxml. Then, in TeamCity you should use this file as a build step. Here is an example, assuming you have **Test** configuration next to **Debug** and **Release** in Visual Studio:

Test.pubxml

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
        <AllowUntrustedCertificate>True</AllowUntrustedCertificate>
        <Configuration>Test</Configuration>
        <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Test</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
        <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
        <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>http://your-website:8080/</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
        <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>False</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
        <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
        <MSDeployServiceURL>server-name</MSDeployServiceURL>
        <DeployIisAppPath>SITE_NAME_ON_IIS</DeployIisAppPath>
        <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
        <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
        <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
        <EnableMSDeployBackup>False</EnableMSDeployBackup>
        <UserName>UserNameWithPermission</UserName>
        <_SavePWD>True</_SavePWD>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Command line parameters:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true
/p:PublishProfile="%teamcity.build.workingDir%\PathToConfiguration\Test.pubxml"
/p:SolutionDir="%teamcity.build.workingDir%"
/p:Password=PASSWORD
```

Build file path should be your *.csproj file:

[TeamCity Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnYhg.png)